# How to set orientation while playing video from sd card in android?

Tags: android, video, orientation

i recored video using default video player in LandScape mode and i saved that video file in sd card. When i select that video file into my application it should be played in portrait mode.

i am using the following logic for recording video:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
}
```

finally, my requirement is: if i recorded video either portrait or landscape mode, it should be played in portrait mode in my application..

Please guide me how to do this. Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

Try to force your activity to portrait:

```
myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```